# Как работает return Java

Tags: java, return

Изучая Java в голове никак не укладывается - как работает return и в каких случаях его используют. Перечитал много разной информации и порешал для себя много разных задач.
Придумав для себя задачку создать простенький калькулятор (если это вообще можно назвать таковым)

```
public static int Plus()
   {
       System.out.print("Сколько чисел вы хотите сложить?:" );
       Scanner count = new Scanner(System.in);
       int num = count.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Количество чисел которые вы хотите сложить = " + num);
       int [] index = new int[num];
       int sum = 0;
       //System.out.println("Text  lenght = " + index.length);
       for (int i=0; i<index.length; i++)
       {
           System.out.print("Введите ["+i+"] число: ");
           int znach = count.nextInt();
           index[i] = znach;
           System.out.println("Значение элемента ["+i+"] = " + index[i]);
           sum = index[i]+sum;
       }

       return sum;
   }

}
```

При вызове метода в main - все проходит удачно и даже выдает верный результат

```
if (YM == 1) {
            System.out.println("Сумма значений = " + Plus());
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Другие действия временно недоступны!!!!");

        }
```

Однако до меня так и не доходит, почему после выполнения первого условия сначала выполняется метод Plus() - а только потом после окончания действия вызывается  System.out.println с результатом. Как это работает? Заранее благодарен за объяснение данного момента

Comment: Этот вопрос связан с `return` почти никак. Тут все логично: как вызвать метод `System.out.printnl()`, если аргумент ещё не готов - его надо сделать из предоставленного выражения.

Comment: т.е получается сначала у нас в методе находится аргумент и только после этого вызывается возвращаемое значение нашего результата?

Comment: В вашем случае вызывается метод `Plus`, потом создание строки, а только потом `System.out.println` Смысла в вызове `System.out.println` с выражением в качестве аргумента функции в Java нет.

Comment: Как бы вы себе представляли вызов принта раньше чем создалить для него аргументы?

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение! Вроде более менее все встало на свои места
Еще небольшой вопрос к вам, а не могли бы вы сказать, адекватен ли в моем случае такой подход к решению задачи? Либо стоило просто без возвращаемого значения решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Ну, в вопросе вы не описали задачу полностью.

Comment: задачу я себе ставил простую: сложение такого количества чисел - которое введет пользователь (кол-во чисел и их значения вводятся пользователем)

Comment: На мой взгляд - если задача решена, то дальше делается оптимизация, а это дело вкуса. Но если хотите получить более объективные ответы, то сделайте отдельный вопрос на эту тему.

Comment: еще раз спасибо! Ответ на свой вопрос я в любом случае получил и понял как это работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это

```
System.out.println("Сумма значений = " + Plus());
```

работает вот так:

```
int temp1 = Plus();
String temp2 = "Сумма значений = " + temp1;
System.out.println(temp2);
```